# Axios - Request header content-type was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list - ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, axios

I'm new to a lot of this technology, but I think I've diagnosed my issue and need some help. I've seen numerous posts on SO regarding this issue, but none have worked, though they have helped me diagnose issue.

I believe the issue is when I send the Header `Content-Type` w/ my pre-flight w/ Axios, it fails. This is possibly due to lower/case upper case? The error has lower case, but I tried both on the server without luck.

Basically, if I don't specify any header and Axios uses `json` as content-type, it works, but as soon as I specify `Content-Type` my pre-flight fails (even though I think post would work..).

Here is the `elasticsearch.yml`

```yaml
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length
#http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

Here is my JS that I'm testing BTW w/ an Office Add-In solution in Visual Studio 2017 which I think is using IE as a browser.

Main Func:

```js
var URL = "https://elasticsearch:9200/users/_search"
const data = {
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "freesoftwareservers"
        }
    }
};
Do_Axios('get', URL, data, null, false)
Do_Axios('post', URL, data, null, false)
```

`Do_Axios`:

```js
async function Do_Axios(method, URL, data, headers, withCredentials) {
    return axios({
        method: method,
        url: URL,
        withCredentials: withCredentials,
        //contentType: 'application/json', // does nothing
        //data: JSON.stringify(data), //Causes urlformencoded which is wrong
        data: data, //caues type to be json and I get error
        headers: {
            //"Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Axios " + method + " response:");
            console.log(response)
            return response;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Note: I can get/post if I comment out //data but then the post doesn't run my query. If I uncomment `data` then `Axios` uses `urlformencoded` but that doesn't work.

For now, I've been able to search API via `urlformencoded` queries, but I'd like to fix my ability to POST correctly to resolve future errors. I'm unsure if issue should be pointed to `Axios` or `Elasticsearch` if I open a request.

Comment: I guess this makes me think its more of an `Elasticsearch` issue on the backend, but I can `POST` fine using `Postman`, but thats not `CORS` I dont think?... A number of variables for me to consider.

Comment: 1) Axios automatically sets the appropriate content-type header for the data passed in for POST, PUT, PATCH requests so you do not need to manually set it. 2) GET requests sent from a browser do not require a content-type header because they cannot send a request body (using either XHR which is what Axios uses or fetch). I know [ElasticSearch supports GET requests with body](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16024) for _"reasons"_ but that's also why they introduced the POST method.

Comment: Ah, don't stringify the `data` in Axios, then you won't need to set a content-type header; just pass it your object and let Axios figure out what headers to use. Also, you cannot use `allow-credentials` with `*` origins. ElasticSearch doesn't even use cookie authentication so I don't know why you'd need it anyway

Comment: @Phil if I stringigy the `data` it uses `urlformencded` which is incorrect, so I removed that part, and it sets the `Content-Type` to `json` and then I get the error.

Comment: I'm not sure if you caught what I was saying earlier but you simply cannot send a GET request with body from a browser; they just don't support that at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these snippets and this was the magic that needed added to my NGINX Proxy configuration which is where the issue was:

```
proxy_pass_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
proxy_pass_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods;
proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type';
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
```

https://gist.github.com/sahilsk/b16cb51387847e6c3329